# How to compare value of second column with same values of first column in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

How to extract and compare values of second column in a data frame for all the same values of first column in same data frame?

I have a data frame as 'df':

```
Name         Datetime
Bob          26-04-2018 12:00:00
Claire       26-04-2018 12:00:00
Bob          26-04-2018 12:30:00
Grace        27-04-2018 08:30:00
Bob          27-04-2018 09:30:00
```

I want to add a new column to the data frame as df['Id'] such that, for users having same names, if the datetime values have a difference of not more than 30 min, they would be assigned the same value of Id, and if the datetime difference is greater than 30 min, then it would be assigned a different id.

I think it could be achieved using iterating over loops but I am not sure how to do it. Also, is there a better way to do this as I have a huge data set?

My expected output of the data frame would be as:

```
Name         Datetime                 Id
Bob          26-04-2018 12:00:00      1
Claire       26-04-2018 12:00:00      2
Bob          26-04-2018 12:10:00      1
Bob          26-04-2018 12:20:00      1
Claire       27-04-2018 08:30:00      3
Bob          27-04-2018 09:30:00      4
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: How did you get a 12:10 and 12:20 record in your results?

Comment: @ScottBoston I added them manually to clearly state the expected results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is simple using `groupby`, `grouper` and `ngroup` as follows:

```
df['Id'] = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='30T', key='Datetime'), 'Name']).ngroup().add(1)


Out[423]:
     Name            Datetime  Id
0     Bob 2018-04-26 12:00:00   1
1  Claire 2018-04-26 12:00:00   2
2     Bob 2018-04-26 12:10:00   1
3     Bob 2018-04-26 12:20:00   1
4  Claire 2018-04-27 08:30:00   3
5     Bob 2018-04-27 09:30:00   4
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you think its possible to use same approach if I want to check if user "Bob" has a data point with a timestamp of 30 min after as well(i.e. after 12.30.00), then both groups would need to be combined in one single group with one Id?

Comment: I am looking to combine all data points for a user (that have same name) and whose datetime values are having consecutive 30 minute intervals into one group with a unique Id. Basically I want to create same Ids for users such that their inactivity is not more than 30 minute. For users that have inactivity more than 30 minute, will be assigned another Id. Is it possible to use similar approach? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Jupyter: I don't clearly understand your description of `consecutive 30 minute intervals` and `inactivity more than 30 minute`. It sounds really similar to this question, but I can't answer positively. Could you post a new question on it with more explanations, samples and desired output. The comment section is too short to provide enough detail. When posting new question, you may link back to this question to provide more context.

Comment: I have posted the question with details.   https://stackoverflow.com/q/56978362/3873482                                        
   Really appreciate the help!

Comment: @Jupyter: I answered your other question. Just check it

Answer (score 2):

I would sort the dataframe on Name, Datetime to identify the different groups, then assign each group an Id value in original Dataframe order.

Code could be:

```
# sort data frame on Name and datetime
df.sort_values(['Name', 'Datetime'], inplace=True)
df1 = df.shift()
# identify new Ids
df.loc[(df1.Name!=df.Name)
       |(df.Datetime-df1.Datetime>pd.Timedelta(minutes=30)), 'tmp'] = 1
del df1   # non longer usefull

# ok, one different tmp value for each group
df['tmp'] = df['tmp'].cumsum().ffill()

# compute Ids in original dataframe orders
ids = pd.DataFrame(df['tmp'].drop_duplicates().sort_index())
ids['Id'] = ids.reset_index(drop=True).index + 1

# and get the expected result
df = df.reset_index().merge(ids, on='tmp').set_index('index').sort_index()\
     .drop(columns='tmp').rename_axis(None)
```

It gives as expected:

```
     Name            Datetime  Id
0     Bob 2018-04-26 12:00:00   1
1  Claire 2018-04-26 12:00:00   2
2     Bob 2018-04-26 12:10:00   1
3     Bob 2018-04-26 12:20:00   1
4  Claire 2018-04-27 08:30:00   3
5     Bob 2018-04-27 09:30:00   4
```