# How to assign a unique ID for different groups in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

How to assign unique IDs to groups created in pandas dataframe based on certain conditions. 
For example: I have a dataframe named as df with the following structure:Name identifies the user, and datetime identifies the date/time at which the user is accessing a resource.

```
Name         Datetime 
Bob          26-04-2018 12:00:00 
Claire       26-04-2018 12:00:00 
Bob          26-04-2018 12:10:00 
Bob          26-04-2018 12:30:00 
Grace        27-04-2018 08:30:00 
Bob          27-04-2018 09:30:00 
Bob          27-04-2018 09:40:00 
Bob          27-04-2018 10:00:00 
Bob          27-04-2018 10:30:00 
Bob          27-04-2018 11:30:00
```

I would like to create sessions for the users such that, users with same name and datetime values accessing the resource do not exceed more than 30 minutes would be assigned a unique session. However, if the user shows some inactivity for more than 30 minutes in accessing the resource, the same user would be assigned a different session for the next time user access the resource.

My expected output would be as shown.

User Bob on 27-04-2018, accessed the resource at 9.30, second time @ 9.40, third time @ 10.00, fourth time @10.30 -> all with Session 4. But next time user Bob access @ 11.30 so time difference exceeds 30 minutes as Bob has been inactive for more than 30 minutes, so next session would be assigned to him.

```
Name         Datetime                    Id
Bob          26-04-2018 12:00:00          1
Claire       26-04-2018 12:00:00          2
Bob          26-04-2018 12:10:00          1
Bob          26-04-2018 12:30:00          1
Grace        27-04-2018 08:30:00          3
Bob          27-04-2018 09:30:00          4
Bob          27-04-2018 09:40:00          4
Bob          27-04-2018 10:00:00          4
Bob          27-04-2018 10:30:00          4
Bob          27-04-2018 11:30:00          5
```

Thank you for your help!
Link to previous question: [How to compare value of second column with same values of first column in pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56960065/3873482)

Comment: Also just realized this seems to be the same as your other question, just with a slightly better example (here). @SergeBallesta provides the correct logic in his answer there to uniquely label groups. My solution turns out to be very similar, just slightly more compact, and without a merge. You might consider accepting his solution there, or closing as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your explanation at the near bottom is really helpful to understand it.

You need to groupby on `Name` and a `groupID` (don't confuse this `groupID` with your final `Id`) and call `ngroup` to return `Id`. The main thing is how to define this `groupID`. To create `groupID`, you need `sort_values` to separate each `Name` and `Datetime` into ascending order. Groupby `Name` and find differences in `Datetime` between consecutive rows within each group of `Name` (within the same `Name`). Using `gt` to check greater than 30mins and `cumsum` to get `groupID`. `sort_index` to reverse back to original order and assign to `s` as follows:

```
s = df.sort_values(['Name','Datetime']).groupby('Name').Datetime.diff() \
      .gt(pd.Timedelta(minutes=30)).cumsum().sort_index()
```

Next, groupby `Name` and `s` with `sort=False` to reserve the original order and call `ngroup` plus 1.

```
df['Id'] = df.groupby(['Name', s], sort=False).ngroup().add(1)

Out[834]:
     Name            Datetime  Id
0     Bob 2018-04-26 12:00:00   1
1  Claire 2018-04-26 12:00:00   2
2     Bob 2018-04-26 12:10:00   1
3     Bob 2018-04-26 12:30:00   1
4   Grace 2018-04-27 08:30:00   3
5     Bob 2018-04-27 09:30:00   4
6     Bob 2018-04-27 09:40:00   4
7     Bob 2018-04-27 10:00:00   4
8     Bob 2018-04-27 10:30:00   4
9     Bob 2018-04-27 11:30:00   5
```

Answer (score 2):

`sort` and find the time difference (`'td'`) for successive actions. `cumsum` a Boolean Series to form groups of successive actions within 30 minutes of the last. `ngroup` labels the groups.

The `sort_index` before the groupby can be removed if you don't care which label the groups get, but this ensures they're ordered based on the original order.

```
df = df.sort_values(['Name', 'Datetime'])
df['td'] = df.Datetime.diff().mask(df.Name.ne(df.Name.shift()))
                             # Only calculate diff within same Name
df['Id'] = (df.sort_index()
              .groupby(['Name', df['td'].gt(pd.Timedelta('30min')).cumsum()], sort=False)
              .ngroup()+1)
df = df.sort_index()
```

#### Output:

`td` left in for clarity

```
     Name            Datetime       td  Id
0     Bob 2018-04-26 12:00:00      NaT   1
1  Claire 2018-04-26 12:00:00      NaT   2
2     Bob 2018-04-26 12:10:00 00:10:00   1
3     Bob 2018-04-26 12:30:00 00:20:00   1
4   Grace 2018-04-27 08:30:00      NaT   3
5     Bob 2018-04-27 09:30:00 21:00:00   4
6     Bob 2018-04-27 09:40:00 00:10:00   4
7     Bob 2018-04-27 10:00:00 00:20:00   4
8     Bob 2018-04-27 10:30:00 00:30:00   4
9     Bob 2018-04-27 11:30:00 01:00:00   5
```